# Need VSCode sendSequence keybindings for previous command, next command, move to start of line, move to end of line terminal commands

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

#### My current custom keybindings

```
    {
        "key": "alt+b",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
        "when": "terminalFocus",
        "args": {
            "text": "\u0017"
        }
    },
    {
        "key": "alt+j",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
        "args": { "text": "\u001bb" }
      },
      {
        "key": "alt+l",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
        "args": { "text": "\u001bf" }
      },
    {
        "key": "alt+n",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
        "when": "terminalFocus",
        "args": {
            "text": "\u001bd"
        }
```

These work well with 1.45 update (integrated terminal update)

[Reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_send-text-from-a-keybinding) - but I need more Information

I want to use **'ijkl'** keys like **'wasd'** gaming standard like my custom project [intuiter](https://github.com/sungle3737/intuiter)

#### So My Idea is

- Can we send sequence to terminal to show **Previous Command/Next command** (like when we click Up/Down Arrow)
- moveToLineStart/moveToLineEnd sequence is removed with this update(sorry I can't find or make sequence) can we get this effect by `sendSequence`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Can we `sendSequence` to terminal to show Previous Command/Next Command (like when we click Up/Down Arrow)"

```
  {
    "key": "alt+x",    // or whatever you choose
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {
      "text": "\u001b[A\n"
  }

//  1 up arrow or previous command, works in cmd, git bash and powershell
//  the \n at the end makes it execute the previous command immediately, 
//  leave it off if you don't want to do that
//  \u000d, a carriage return, is equivalent to \n if you prefer to use that, so
//  \u001b[A\u000d does the same thing as \u001b[A\n

>    /** Carriage Return (Caret = ^M, C = \r) */   
>      export const CR  = '\x0d';




  {
    "key": "alt+y",    // or whatever you choose
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {
      "text": "\u001b[B\n"
  }  

//  1 down arrow
//  see comment above about immediate command execution
```

For these arrow commands, see https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html

> **Functions using CSI , ordered by the final character(s)**
>
> **CSI Ps A**  Cursor Up Ps Times (default = 1) (CUU).
>
> **CSI Ps B**  Cursor Down Ps Times (default = 1) (CUD).

This part `\u001b[` is the escape sequence or `CSI` referred to in the document.  Follow that with an `A` for cursur up (up arrow) so `\u001b[A`  or follow the escape sequence with a `B` for a down arrow, so `\u001b[B`.

[Theoretically, you should be able to do `\u001b[2A` for 2 (the `Ps` part referred to above) up arrows at once but that never seems to work in vscode for me in vscode.]

---

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+e",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": { "text": "\u0005" },   // move cursor to end of line, bash at least
    "when": "terminalFocus"
  },

  {
    "key": "ctrl+a",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": { "text": "\u0001" },   // move cursor to start of line, bash at least
    "when": "terminalFocus"
  },
```

I used the usual keybindings - at least in bash - for go to the start or end of the command line.  See, e.g., http://teohm.com/blog/shortcuts-to-move-faster-in-bash-command-line/

From this document https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/blob/0e45909c7e79c83452493d2cd46d99c0a0bb585f/src/common/data/EscapeSequences.ts

we see that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is :

> /** Start of Heading (Caret = ^A) */   [that's Ctrl+A]
>      export const SOH = '\x01';

so I used `\u0001` the unicode sequence to replace that listed `\x01` which won't work with the `sendSequence` command.

Likewise, to send a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to the terminal for the go to the end of the command line, we see that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> is :

> /** Enquiry (Caret = ^E) */   [that's Ctrl+E]
>      export const ENQ = '\x05';

or unicode `\u0005`.

Now, your terminal shell might use something other than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> for go to start/end of the command line.  If my keybindings don't work for you, find out what your shell uses for go to start/end and see if they are in https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/blob/0e45909c7e79c83452493d2cd46d99c0a0bb585f/src/common/data/EscapeSequences.ts